# Form a column out of a Datetime field python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, if-statement

Here is the DataFrame column and its datatype

```
df['Hours'].head()
OutPut: 

0   00:00:00
1   00:00:00
2   11:38:00
3   08:40:00
Name: Hours, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I want to conditionally form anaother column from it, such that it will look like.

```
Hours        Test
00:00:00     N/A
00:00:00     N/A
11:38:00     02:38:00
08:40:00     Under Worked
```

Where ,

```
if df['Hours'] == '00:00:00':
  df[Test] = 'N/A'
elif (df['Hours'].dt.total_seconds()//3600) < 9:
  df['Test'] = 'Under Worked' 
else:
  df['Test'] = (df['Hours'].dt.total_seconds()//3600)-9
```

But it gives me error

```
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Also I tried with using `np.select`

```
conditions = [
(str(df['Hours']) == '0 days 00:00:00'),
(df['Hours'].dt.total_seconds()//3600) < 9]
choices = ['NA', 'Worked Under']
df['Test'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=(df['Hours'].dt.total_seconds()//3600)-9)
```

This is the error I get

```
ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions
```

How can it be solved?

Comment: I think here is best use `np.select`

Comment: Can you add it to question?

Comment: @jezrael I added it

Comment: np.select is the good choice, but the error is explicit here. You have put 2 conditions, and 3 choices. The program cannot decide for you.

Comment: @IMCoins I made a mistake while pasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df1['Hours'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Hours'])

conditions = [df1['Hours'] == pd.Timedelta(0), df1['Hours'] < pd.Timedelta(9, unit='H')]
choices = ['N/A', 'Under Worked']

s = df1['Hours'].sub(pd.Timedelta(9, unit='h')).astype(str).str[7:15]

df1['OT'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=s)
print (df1)
     Hours          Test            OT
0 00:00:00           N/A           N/A
1 00:00:00           N/A           N/A
2 11:38:00      02:38:00      02:38:00
3 08:40:00  Under Worked  Under Worked
```

Comment: how you got `df1['Test'] `column? , because `OT` column doesn't include minutes part